# Vertical line between nav buttons using layout_weight

Tags: android, tablelayout

I have a table layout to display the buttons of my nav bar horizontaly and with equal size. For that I use `android:layout_weight` but I want to put between the buttons of my nav bar a fancy vertical line [(as you can see here for example between "messages" and "video call")](http://www.google.fr/imgres?imgurl=http%3A%2F%2Fcdn.mactrast.com%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2013%2F05%2Fgoogle_plus_hangout_screenshots.jpg&imgrefurl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mactrast.com%2F2013%2F05%2Fgoogle-introduces-google-hangouts-cross-platform-messaging-service%2F&h=505&w=853&tbnid=w3R2V02DXkin6M%3A&zoom=1&docid=ruuKDo9O3b93FM&ei=AxgTVOH9B8LVavbLgsAF&tbm=isch&client=firefox-a&iact=rc&uact=3&dur=886&page=1&start=0&ndsp=41&ved=0CEoQrQMwDQ).
*I've tried several ways to do that with no success, the last one beeing use a `marginRight` on the buttons, but it seems it won't work with `android:layout_weight.*

Here is my `TableLayout`

```
<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:stretchColumns="1"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="#c0c0c0">
    <TableRow>
      <Button
         android:id="@+id/picture"
         android:layout_width="0dip"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:padding="0dip"
         android:layout_margin="0dip"

         android:layout_weight="1"
         android:text="Picture"
         android:background="@drawable/nav_button"
         style="@style/nav_button" />

      <Button
         android:id="@+id/friends"
         android:layout_width="0dip"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_margin="0dip"

         android:layout_weight="1"
         android:padding="0dip"
         android:text="Friends"
         android:background="@drawable/nav_button"
         style="@style/nav_button" />
    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually I don't know why you're using a `TableLayout` but I guess it's not a requirement since you're talking about the NavBar / ActionBar. So I'm suggesting you to use a `LinearLayout` instead in order to show this vertical divider between your two buttons.
Here's how it should work:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:divider="?android:attr/dividerVertical"
    android:dividerPadding="12dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:showDividers="middle">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/picture"
        style="@style/nav_button"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/nav_button"
        android:padding="0dip"
        android:text="Picture" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/friends"
        style="@style/nav_button"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/nav_button"
        android:padding="0dip"
        android:text="Friends" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**Note:** The relevant part is `android:divider` and `android:showDividers`. These are properties that have been added in Android 3.0 (API-Level 10). You can read more about it in the [Docs (click)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html#attr_android:divider).

Answer (score 0):

Between the button tags, insert a view

```
    <View
        android:id="@+id/divider"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Comment: No it doesn't work with the `android:layout_weight="1"` of each button. I could give your view a weight but It will not be 1dp consistently.

Comment: try adding the view without a weight, just add equal weight to the 2 buttons, this works for me in a linear layout.